# How can I access bones/armature/pose mode?

Tags: modeling, rigging

[image: teddy with bones]

So I made a teddy with very simple bones and made him sit, but now I can´t seem to access those bones. How do I get in pose mode? This is how it looks in Edit Mode.

Comment: Select the armature in Object mode then you can select Pose mode from the drop-down or CTRL-Tab will take you straight into Pose mode.

Comment: for the moment you've selected the object, not the armature, you need to switch back to Object mode, then select the armature, then you'll be able to switch it to Pose mode

Comment: Thank you very much!